# Cakephp Data Retrieving only got ID

Tags: cakephp

I am currently retrieving data and set to the view to populate input select field and although I find with name it only shows ID in select field. Here is the code

```
         // retrieve new lead list
     $arrList = $this->NewLead->find('list', array('order' => 'newlead_name'));          

     //set to the view
     $this->set(compact('arrList'));
```

here is the code in view

```
echo $this->Form->select('NewLead', $arrList, array('multiple' => 'true', 'id' => 'NewLeadList'));
```

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
 // retrieve new lead list
     $arrList = $this->NewLead->find('list', array('fields'=>array("id","name_whatever"),'order' => 'newlead_name'));          

     //set to the view
     $this->set(compact('arrList'));
   //here is the code in view
   echo $this->Form->select('NewLead', array('multiple' => 'true', 'id' => 'NewLeadList','options'=>$arrList));
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the problem by adding public $displayField = newlead_name in model.

Comment: You could also simply follow the conventions, ie define the view var as `newLeads`, that way the form helper will pick it up automatically. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements @Patrick